# Why is RPM for mobile is much less than RPM for desktop in Google Adsense?

Tags: google-adsense, monetize

I have about 50% of my website's traffic on mobile devices (iOS and Android.) The RPM for mobile is much worse than RPM for desktop.

Is there any way I should do to increase the RPM?

Data here:

```
PV     | Click   |   CTR   |   CPC  |   RPM 

Desktop
652,183  16,283   2.50%     $0.22    $5.43

High-end mobile devices 
657,782  6,504    0.99%     $0.09    $0.93

Tablets
46,873   657      1.40%     $0.15    $2.08
```

Comment: I have the same issue too, except my RPM for mobile averages to $0

Comment: only 25%? mine is more than 50% less than desktop. Site is very well mobile optimized.. I guess mine problem is in very long pages.. but wanted to figure what one can do in such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your RPM is so low for mobile devices, it is a sign that your site does not display well on mobile devices.   To improve the RPM for mobile devices:

- Show a page that is only as wide as the mobile device.
- Use the viewport meta tag to prevent your site from showing zoomed out with tiny text: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`
- Use ad units sizes that have lots of inventory yet still fit on mobile screens: 320x50 and 300x250
- Like desktop, figure out where on the page to place your advertisements so that they get noticed.   I tend to use a 320x50 near the top of the page (but not the very top) and a 200x250 unit interspersed with the content.

This does require some development work to make mobile devices work well with your site.  I do this with user agent sniffing and rewriting the page server side.   [AdSense recently released responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689) so that you could change your ad sizes using responsive design as well.

Comment: I have all these things on my sites, but my rpm is still far lower than desktop (less than 25%)